# SwiftUI List selected item in composed List

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I am building a File Manager app.

In this App the user can select a specific Folder in a list. There is also the possibility to select the option "All Folders" that is the first element in the list.

I want to keep the selected folder in a AppState class, setting it to `nil` if the user is selecting "All Folders":

```
class AppState: ObservableObject {
    @Published var selectedFolder: Folder?
}
```

```
struct FileListView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject
    var appState: AppState
    
    var body: some View {
        List() {
            FileRowView(
                title: "All Files",
            )
            .onTapGesture {
                appState.selectedFolder = nil
            }
            
            ForEach(filesList) {
                file in
                FileRowView(
                    title: file.title ?? "File unnamed",
                )
                .onTapGesture {
                    appState.selectedFolder = folder
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Even though this code works and `selectedFolder` is updated, the List does not highlight in the View actual selected element. It does not have this "bluish" look and feel usually applied to selected items in a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need the List version that keeps track of selections: `List(selection: )`.
2. Even though the binding selection var is optional, you cannot use `nil` for a List element. `nil` to the List means that nothing is selected.
3. With that List initializer you don't need `onTapGesture`, just give each row a `.tag()` of the same type as your selection var.

here is a simplified example:

```
struct FileListView: View {
    @State var selectedFolder: Int?
    
    var body: some View {
        List(selection: $selectedFolder) {
            Text("All Files")
                .tag(999)
            
            ForEach(0..<10) { file in
                Text("file \(file)")
                    .tag(file)
            }
        }
    }
}
```